# Django/Python Serializing valuequeryset with number of objects limits per call (external service)

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, iteration

I am relatively new to Django and Python and have a quick question on the best way of going about breaking up serialization on object limits as apposed to call limits.  I will be making calls to an external web service that limits the number of objects per call in addition to calls/timeframe.

Currently I am creating a dictionary from a valuequeryset and then serializing.  I have the json producing correctly, but I am looking for the best way to build the json in chunks.  The API I am hitting allows for single object calls, but also calls with up to 5 objects.

For example, I have a queryset with 25 records, what would be the best way to iterate through the list and break it into 5 json payloads which I could then iterate through, build json and fire off.  Using the 5 per call instead of the 1 per call will help with the calls per time frame.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to achieve this is to leverage an existing framework like django-rest-framework.  Rate limiting can be achieved as part of the settings.py -
 http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/

Comment: I went down the path of DRF.  From my understanding, it is a tool used for creating and exposing APIs.  I am also building the calls dynamically at runtime based on mappings and model data, and it really was more work than necessary to override all of the classes for dynamic calls to external services.  I appreciate the quick response though.

Comment: If basic pagination is the goal outside of a framework then you could do something like passing a start parameter with default value of 0.  And then return the last element value with previous response.  For example you call start=5 and in the response it says next=10 so you call start=10 in the next api call.  queryset[start:start+5]